# Asp.net MVC with SimpleMembershipProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, membership, simplemembership

I'm developing a web site using ASP.NET MVC.
For membership, I'm using SimpleMembershipProvider. So, here is a part of my web.config:

This is on my Global.asax, in the Application_Start:

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "Users", "UserID", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```

Well, my problem is in the LogIn.
Apparently, when I use WebSecurity.Login(username, password) it works. I assumed that because when putting it in an IF statement, returns true.
But, when I use WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated.. it ALWAYS return FALSE.
This is my LogIn controller:

```
public ActionResult ToLogIn([Bind(Include = "UserName, Password")] LogInModel _user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (WebSecurity.Login(_user.UserName, _user.Password))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home")
            }

        }
        return View(_user);
    }
```

It works and redirect to the Index Home page, which use a layout where I check the WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated and, as I say before, it always return False.

Comment: You're storing up trouble by going with Simple Membership. Any reason not to go with Asp.Net Identity instead? IMO SimpleMembership is a dead end, and pulling out a membership provider to replace it is a horrendous PITA. If you're in a "green field" environment, I'd urge you to consider Identity instead. You'll get much more mileage out of it.

Comment: @spender Hey, thanks. I'm just an student and I'm doing a "training" for a local company. They just said "use this" and, well, I tried but unsuccessfully.

Comment: You need to set a `FormsAuthentication` cookie by using `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie` to keep user's session till logout. Doing redirect simply not enough, since you need to store user information first. Check `HttpContext.Current.User` to find out user name after login.

Comment: I agree with @spender, learn Identity instead, the other membership systems are off in the sunset.  Impress your employers with your ability to discern the correct technology choice :)  plus, there's loads of canned sample projects around, like on github which demonstrate a complete working sample to get you started

Comment: Thank you so much! ;) @TetsuyaYamamoto

Comment: You're right.. I will try to use Identity. Thank you! @Erikest